# SSRS graph "Category group"

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Hi I have around 10 different names in column.
for example
Resource
RD
Consultant
Business stream
and so on
I like to group by Resource and RD in one graph and rest on the second graph. I have done already for Resource and RD one. Can anyone tell me how to put others in the group but excluding RD and resources from category group.

Comment: update your question add  the tables schema, a proper data sample,  the expected  result   and the code you have already done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I am not sure whether you want to put Resource and RD in a chart or out them in in a group. Below is my design:

1. Resource and RD in a single chart and other streams in another chart:(Set filter in Category Group Properties) like below (I can't upload an image now)
   Filter expression:=iif(Fields!name.Value="a" or Fields!name.Value="b" , true, false)
       operator:=
       values:=true

For another chart, you could change true to false

2. Resource and RD in a group and other steam in another group, they all in the same chart: configure Category Group Properties like below
   Group on and Label use expression=iif(Fields!name.Value="a" or Fields!name.Value="b",1,2). Then you could add [name] field in Series Group

Comment: Thanks for your help.